# Why we use throw key for Exception

Tags: asp.net

Please explain what is significance of  thows keyword for exception

Comment: Because `pitch` wasn't as catchy

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Answer (score 5):

We `throw` exceptions, because someone might `catch` them later.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling in asp.net, is a real art, and especially when you break your application in different chunks of classes and forms. Some time it becomes unimaginably difficult to catch a simple error at runtime without managing exception block. When it comes to extendibility of the application unexpected errors become a night mare for programmers.